# Android Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, navbar

I am new to android app development and in the process of making my first app.

I am trying to create a bottom navigation bar. I have created the actual navigation bar but i am trying to now get it so when i click on that icon it will go to a different page. I currently have it so it will show some text saying you clicked on this button etc. but i am unsure how to make it so it will go to a different page.

This is the code i currently have

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);



    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Action Add Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_exercise:


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity .this, "Action Exercise Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_timer:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Action Timer Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;

        }
    });

}

}
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gymapp.HomePage">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="318dp"
    android:layout_height="198dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/getinshape"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_bar"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is also the code I'm using within the res/menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_exercise"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/exercise"
    android:title="Exercise"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_timer"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_timer"
    android:title="Timer"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />

</menu>
```

Comment: See example [here](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0)

Comment: This is the example i have been using to create what i already have but doesn't directly help me with what i'm asking on this question. I am trying to get it to go to a different layout view/page rather than just having it show text

Comment: Sorry wrong link. Replace fragments on navigation item selected ([example with fragment replace](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Bottom-Navigation-Views))

Comment: Thanks for the link. The issue i now have is every time i try to run the app when following that code it just crashes before even loading before i can do anything?